# Google Books API Branding Compliance issue--infoLink returns "Not found" page

Tags: api, google-api, google-books, google-books-api

I'm working with the Google Books API and the [Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/books/branding#search-results-and-book-information) state that I have to have a prominent link to the Google Books page for each search result. Cool, I'm fine with that.

However:

1. `saleInfo.buyLink` isn't always there in the [API response](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#response_1)
2. `volumeInfo.infoLink` and `volumeInfo.canonicalVolumeLink` <del>sometimes</del> often go to a "Not Found" page (for example [this page](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=DvHDzQEACAAJ), which is supposed to have information for "Lunar Orbiter State Estimation Using Neural Network-based Crater Detection" by Lena Marie Downs [don't ask, I used `faker` to call the API with random keywords and picked a random result])

So my question becomes, is it my responsibility to try to find workarounds for any of that, in order to be compliant? Or should I just go with what Google Books gives me and call it a day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my seeds file to only look for Google Books that have an ebook available with `&filter=ebooks`, and I haven't run into these issues with what it found this time. But I guess the question still stands whether it's up to developers using the API to provide for Google's issues, in case anyone else wants to answer.